# Encrypting and decrypting android expansion file

Tags: encryption, apk, pack, expansion

I have successfully uploaded and published my android app + apk expansion file (with format .obb but is actually a .zip) on Google Play. I would like to set up some protection to it. Are there any ways to do it to acheieve this without using external jar classes like zip4j?

In my obb file I have a few videos (of .mp4) that I need to use my mediaplayer to read it. I want to do this so that only my media player can read the obb file.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @user1607820. Did you find a solution for it? I too need to set up protection using JOBB. Did you find anything? Share with us if u have any solution